# How would I create a reset button for my program relating with the following code?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, reset

I am trying to add a reset button but I can't seem to get it to work. I created a main in order to refer back to it when the button is pressed but no luck. Any ideas?

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import math

def main():
    def closeWin():
        myGui.destroy()                  #Close Window Function


    def kiloFunc():
        myText = kiloMent.get()          #Kilometers to Miles Fuction
        convert = 0.62
        miles = myText * convert
        finalKilo = Label(text = miles,fg='red',justify='center').place(x=200,y=80)


    def mileFunc():
        myText2 = mileMent.get()         #Miles to Kilometers Function
        convertTwo = myText2 // 0.62    
        finalMile = Label(text = convertTwo, fg = 'red',justify='center').place(x=200,y=170)

    myGui = Tk()

    kiloMent = IntVar()
    mileMent = IntVar()

    myGui.title("Distance Converter")
    myGui.geometry("450x200+500+200")

    myLabel = Label(text="Welcome! Please enter your value then choose your option:",fg="blue",justify='center')
    myLabel.pack()

    kiloEntry = Entry(myGui, textvariable = kiloMent,justify='center').pack()

    kilo2milesButton = Button(text = "Kilometers to Miles!", command = kiloFunc).pack()

    mileEntry = Entry(myGui, textvariable = mileMent,justify='center').place(x=130,y=105)

    miles2kiloButton = Button(text = "Miles to Kilometers!", command = mileFunc).place(x=150,y=135)

    reset = Button(text = "Reset Values!", command = main).place(x=10,y=165)

    quit = Button(text="Quit", command = closeWin).place(x=385,y=165)


    myGui.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling `main()` again, you are simply creating another instance of the GUI. What you should do instead is (if I understand correctly), reset the values of the currently existing GUI. You can use the `set()` method of the GUI objects.

Does

```
def reset_values():
    kiloMent.set(0)
    mileMent.set(0)
reset = Button(text="Reset Values!", command=reset_values).place(x=10, y=165)
```

do the trick?

Looking at your code more thoroughly, however, there are some other problems there, as well. To start with, I would suggest not creating a `Label` everytime the user tries to convert a value.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of that! Thank you!

Comment: What other options do I have regarding how to display information if I am not using a label

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    def closeWin():
        myGui.destroy()  # Close Window Function

    def kiloFunc():
        finalKilo.set(kiloMent.get() * 0.62)  # Kilometers to Miles Fuction

    def mileFunc():
        finalMile.set(mileMent.get() // 0.62)  # Miles to Kilometers Function

    def clearFunc():
        kiloMent.set("0")
        mileMent.set("0")
        finalKilo.set("")
        finalMile.set("")

    myGui = Tk()

    kiloMent = IntVar()
    mileMent = IntVar()

    finalKilo = StringVar()
    finalMile = StringVar()

    myGui.title("Distance Converter")
    myGui.geometry("450x200+500+200")

    myLabel = Label(text="Welcome! Please enter your value then choose your option:", fg="blue", justify='center')
    myLabel.pack()

    kiloEntry = Entry(myGui, textvariable=kiloMent, justify='center')
    kiloEntry.pack()

    kilo2milesButton = Button(text="Kilometers to Miles!", command=kiloFunc)
    kilo2milesButton.pack()

    mileEntry = Entry(myGui, textvariable=mileMent, justify='center')
    mileEntry.place(x=130, y=105)

    miles2kiloButton = Button(text="Miles to Kilometers!", command=mileFunc)
    miles2kiloButton.place(x=150, y=135)

    kiloLabel = Label(textvariable=finalKilo, fg='red', justify='center')
    kiloLabel.place(x=200, y=80)

    mileLabel = Label(textvariable=finalMile, fg='red', justify='center')
    mileLabel.place(x=200, y=170)

    reset = Button(text="Reset Values!", command=clearFunc)
    reset.place(x=10, y=165)

    quit = Button(text="Quit", command=closeWin)
    quit.place(x=385, y=165)

    myGui.mainloop()

main()
```

A few notes about your original code besides the ones that Chuck mentioned:

1. The `math` and `sys` imports were unused.
2. You were setting variables equal to `widget.pack()` and `widget.place()`, which are functions that return `None`.

Comment: Return none? Sorry for the stupid question I am fairly new to python. Could you explain more about that?

Comment: `myLabel = Label()` is what you want to do, because it sets the value of `myLabel` to a `Label` widget. But `myLabel = Label().pack()` sets the value of `myLabel` to `None`, because it is equivalent to `temp = Label(); myLabel = temp.pack()`. `pack()` is a function that returns the value `None`.