# How to change the text in an entry widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a button that resets a login form, and I have added a date of birth section to it.  I am able to make everything be reset back to its original form, however, how do I change the text that is entered in the entry widget back to what it was.

```
dayV = tk.StringVar(self, value = "DD")
monthV = tk.StringVar(self, value = "MM")
yearV = tk.StringVar(self, value = "YYYY")

dayE = tk.Entry(self, font = BASIC_FONT, textvariable = dayV, width = 5, justify = "center")
dayE.pack()

monthE = tk.Entry(self, font = BASIC_FONT, textvariable = monthV, width = 5, justify = "center")
monthE.pack()

yearE = tk.Entry(self, font = BASIC_FONT, textvariable = yearV, width = 5, justify = "center")
yearE.pack()
```

If the user changes the DD to say 12, then clicks the reset button, I want it to go back to DD.  How do you do this?

Comment: Have you tried to add button with function that set's the values to 0? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994811/how-would-i-create-a-reset-button-for-my-program-relating-with-the-following-cod/35994963

Comment: Just tried it and it works, thank you very much.  I will add this as the answer to the question.

Comment: Added it as an answer. Hope it helped.

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in the Entry documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment section, it has been answered in another question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994811/how-would-i-create-a-reset-button-for-my-program-relating-with-the-following-cod/35994963)

So, the idea is to create a function that resets the values into 0.

Code:

```
def reset_values():
    kiloMent.set(0)
    mileMent.set(0)
reset = Button(text="Reset Values!", command=reset_values).place(x=10, y=165)
```